# App validation error

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, validation, submit

“ScenesAndLayers” does not contain a single–bundle application or contains multiple products. Please select another archive, or adjust your scheme to create a single–bundle application.

This is the error I am getting when I have archived my app and go to validate it. What is happening here? How do I fix this?

Comment: What is your code? Be specific when you asking.

Comment: What did you archive? Sounds like you archived more than just what you needed to upload.

Comment: [Here](http://www.weston-fl.com/blog/?p=2429) is one solution to this exact issue. Have a look.

Answer (score 0):

This is because your app probably uses static libraries that are marked with `Skip Install = NO`.